# PHP $_GET var won't get anything after %20

Tags: php

I have got this php

```
$_GET['u'];
```

And this url

```
user?u=Murad%20Shahmmadli
```

So the problem is `$_GET['u']` only gets `'Murad'` and not `Shahmmadli`

Comment: post url, how's you passing it ? i think u are using quotes in url for value

Comment: posting whole code is better

Comment: No i have Murad%20Shahmmadli in my url and i get it with $_GET['u' @ManinderpreetSingh]

Comment: can you post more details?

Comment: What part of it exactly?Because i use $_GET in a lot of parts @f_anto

Comment: paste your url only

Comment: one of those is oke

Comment: Now it is Murad+Shahmmadli and it is still getting only Murad @Anant

Comment: check here:- https://eval.in/598872

Comment: @Khaleesi  did you get it what i suggests?